# ruby koans shuffle what is happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shuffle

Can't figure out this one of the [ruby koans](http://rubykoans.com/). Maybe someone could help?`The answers you seek...
  undefined method`to_a_shuffle' for 1..5:Range

Please meditate on the following code:
  /Users/nicholaskelly/koans/koans/about_dice_project.rb:12:in `roll'
  /Users/nicholaskelly/koans/koans/about_dice_project.rb:24:in`test_rolling_the_dice_returns_a_set_of_integers_between_1_and_6'`

and here is about_dice_project.rb12:

```
@values = (1..number).to_a_shuffle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method named `to_a_shuffle`. You need to apply `to_a` to a range then `shuffle` that array.

```
@values = (1..number).to_a.shuffle
```